# Conditional transitive link libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm struggling with the CMake "Config"-based package description when using two depending packages where the upstream package has optional link libraries.

Suppose you have `libA` that optionally uses zip functionality (say by some option `USE_ZLIB` in `libA`'s `CMakeLists.txt`). This means `libA` will optionally have `-lz` in its `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` (exported into `liba-config.cmake`).
Now, if you have a `libB` using `libA` via `find_package(libA)`, how do you know if `libA` has been built with or without zlib support when both libraries are installed and exported with CMake's package config system?

I know that the link library information is treated transitively and will be propagated to the link libraries of `libB`, hence `-lz` will appear whenever linking against `libB`. However, the `PATH` to libz is nowhere included; consequently, the link fails with "could not find library z" unless you magically knew that `libz` is a link library of `libA` and where to include it from.
Including the absolute path to `libz` in `libA`'s config is also not the way to go, as it ruins the portability over different systems.

Edit: I've been getting replies suggesting to use `target_link_libraries(libA PRIVATE z)`, e.g. declaring the (in fact internal to libA) libz a private library. Unfortunately this does not solve the issue, as CMake automatically adds any `PRIVATE`-marked link library to the `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` list via `$<LINK_ONLY:z>`. This shows the necessity of having `-lz` appear in the exported link library list in another way (and that CMake export script authors understand the transitive issue).

Comment: why doesn't `liba-config.cmake` contain a  `find_package(ZLIB)` and link against `${ZLIB_LIBRARIES}`?

Comment: well the xxx-config.cmake files are generated by CMake's install(EXPORT ..) command, this is something you're not intended to fuzz with. sure, i have a ton of dirty hacks in my mind to solve the problem, but i'm interested if there is a correct CMake-native way of dealing with this.

Comment: Just for your information: http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake-developers/2015-April/025034.html

Comment: thanks @ruslo, that's going in the same direction!

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to do this is making your `liba-config.cmake` a template and [configure_file()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/configure_file.html) it to populate it with information about build options.

For example, your `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
if(ZLIB_FOUND)
... # link with ZLIB
set(BUILT_WITH_ZLIB 1)
endif()
... # more options
configure_file(alib-config.cmake.in alib-config.cmake)
```

Now, `liba-config.cmake.in` should have

```
set(BUILT_WITH_ZLIB @BUILT_WITH_ZLIB@)
if(BUILT_WTH_ZLIB)
# append lz to ALIB_LIBRARIES or whetever you variable is called
endif()
```

After configuration `alib-config.cmake` would contain `set(BUILT_WITH_ZLIB 0)` or `set(BUILT_WITH_ZLIB 1)` depending on its value in CMake.

Comment: Thanks, but that's a 50/50 helpful. For me this is one of the "dirty hacks" one could come up with. As in my comment, the config files are created by CMake and i dont intend to mess with that (they might change/improve over time and i dont want to end up updating templates). but the true thing is, ultimately all information about the package MUST be contained in the config files if that is to be the means of inter-package communication.